# ComboBox onchange for VB Script

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am a newbie when it comes to VB Script and I am trying to make a Combo box with an onchange event.

Here is the code that i have so far:

```
' Report Version
                If FieldID = 36 Then
                    If IsLIXIJob Then
                        'first get the field id of the fields you want to hide or display
                        SQLQuery =  "SELECT FieldID, FieldName FROM Fields WITH (NOLOCK) " & _
                                    " WHERE [Table] = 'Valuations' AND " & _
                                    "       FieldName IN ('RiskTenderPriceDisplay', 'RiskProgressPaymentScheduleDisplay')"
                        Set LIXITBEFields = dbConn.Execute(SQLQuery)

                        TBEFieldsOn = ""
                        TBEFieldsOff = ""
                        If Not LIXITBEFields.EOF Then
                            Do While Not LIXITBEFields.EoF
                                TBEFieldsOn = TBEFieldsOn & "if (IsDefined ('StandardField_" & LIXITBEFields ("FieldID") & "')) $('StandardField_" & LIXITBEFields ("FieldID") & "').style.display = ''; " & vbCrLf
                                TBEFieldsOff = TBEFieldsOff & "if (IsDefined ('StandardField_" & LIXITBEFields ("FieldID") & "')) $('StandardField_" & LIXITBEFields ("FieldID") & "').style.display = 'none'; " & vbCrLf

                                LIXITBEFields.MoveNext ()
                            Loop
                        End If

                        LIXITBEFields.Close ()
                        Set LIXITBEFields = Nothing
                    End If


                    Select Case Output 
                        Case 0
                            RunAtEnd = "AllFields(); " & TBEFieldsOff
                        Case 1
                            RunAtEnd = "StandardMode(); " & TBEFieldsOff
                        Case 2
                            RunAtEnd = "StrataMode();" & TBEFieldsOff
                        Case 3
                            RunAtEnd = "TBEMode();" & TBEFieldsOn
                        Case 4
                            RunAtEnd = "TBEUnitMode();" & TBEFieldsOn
                        Case 5
                            RunAtEnd = "RenoMode(); " & TBEFieldsOff
                        Case 6
                            RunAtEnd = "RenoUnitMode(); " & TBEFieldsOff
                        Case 7
                            RunAtEnd = "VacantLandMode();" & TBEFieldsOff
                    End Select

                    %>

                    <select name="ReportList" id="ReportList" onchange="ReportList_SelectedIndexChanged()">
                        <option value="All Fields">All Fields</option>
                        <option value="Existing Building">Existing Building</option>
                        <option value="xisting Building - Strata">Existing Building - Strata</option>
                        <option value="To Be Erected">To Be Erected</option>
                        <option value="To Be Erected - Strata">To Be Erected - Strata</option>
                        <option value="Extension & Renovation">Extension & Renovation</option>
                        <option value="Extension & Renovation - Strata">Extension & Renovation - Strata</option>
                        <option value="Vacant Land">Vacant Land</option>
                    </select>

                    <%                                              
                End If
```

I tried making a Sub statement enclosing the Select Case but it didn't work.
I also made a Private Sub outside the If statement and called in on the onchange for the comboBox:

```
Private Sub ReportList_SelectedIndexChanged()
    Dim selectedInd 
    selectedInd = ReportList.SelectedIndex
    Dim selectedIt 
    selectedIt = ReportList.SelectedItem.Text

    If selectedIt = "All Fields" Then
        RunAtEnd = "AllFields(); " & TBEFieldsOff
    End If
    If selectedIt = "Existing Building" Then
        RunAtEnd = "StandardMode(); " & TBEFieldsOff
    End If
    If selectedIt = "Existing Building - Strata" Then
        RunAtEnd = "StrataMode();" & TBEFieldsOff
    End If
    If selectedIt = "To Be Erected" Then
        RunAtEnd = "TBEMode();" & TBEFieldsOn
    End If
    If selectedIt = "To Be Erected - Strata" Then
        RunAtEnd = "TBEUnitMode();" & TBEFieldsOn
    End If
    If selectedIt = "Extension & Renovation" Then
        RunAtEnd = "RenoMode(); " & TBEFieldsOff
    End If
    If selectedIt = "Extension & Renovation - Strata" Then
        RunAtEnd = "RenoUnitMode(); " & TBEFieldsOff
    End If
    If selectedIt = "Vacant Land" Then
        RunAtEnd = "VacantLandMode();" & TBEFieldsOff
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm really stuck at this bit. Anyway I can make this work?

Comment: what error you got? Which statement its failing ? Did you try to debug the code. If you are not aware of debugging, use F8 to debug it and F5 to run it.

Comment: @MukulVarshney I think I am not calling the function correctly because it's not spouting an error it just doesn't work. I can't do a debug because i am doing the edit on a remote desktop and the only text editor is EditPlus.

Comment: in that case create a function to write logs to a file. You can localize the error by the log file.

Comment: As a practice, generally I use UCASE$() for string comaprison, selectedIt = UCASE$(ReportList.SelectedItem.Text) and then compare with all caps

Comment: What is it you expect `RunAtEnd` to do?, at the moment you just populate it with a string...you don't `Response.Write()` back to the client, you don't use `ExecuteGlobal()` to dynamically execute it...hard to see what you are intending. There is also some really poor practice when it comes to Function / Sub writing that you should consider correcting before you go any further.

Comment: @MukulVarshney sounds like you are talking about VBA not VBScript, in fact the OP is using Classic ASP *(note the `<% %>` pre-processing tags)* so debugging without having server-side debugging enabled isn't as easy *(even then it doesn't always work)* as `F8` and `F5` in a debugger.

Comment: It's also unclear what code is *server-side* and what code is *client-side*, are you using both VBScript for the client and in Classic ASP on the server?